# How to fix "symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64" - Vs Code - C program - Mac M1

Tags: c, macos, vscode-extensions, cs50, arm64

I'm totally a newbie in computer science and I'm currently learning CS50 with C program on VS code first. Plus, I'm using Mac M1 to run the code.

HERE'S MY CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf ("helloworld\n");
}
```

I have run code "helloworld" multiple times but the system always said:

**cc     hello1.c   -o hello1**

**Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:**

**"_main", referenced from:**

**implicit entry/start for main executable**

**ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64**

**clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

I found some ways on many platforms and tried them including:

- Setup Homebrew
- Click "Run In Terminal" and "Save file before run" in setting

However, all of them didn't work in my case and I'm quite frustrated now. I really appreciate all of your support and help to solve this issue.
Thank you so much!

Comment: The error messages indicate the source file you compiled, `hello1.c`, does not contain a definition for the `main` function. Although you show source code containing `main`, that does not appear to be the source code that is stored in the file `hello1.c`.

Comment: So could you please let me know how can I resolve it?

Comment: Make sure `hello1.c` contains the source code you thought it did.

Comment: I'm so sorry for asking but how can I make sure that file contains source code like main? Do you recommend any steps to resolve it?

Comment: Look at the contents of your file. Open it with a text editor or use the `cat` command to print its contents.

Comment: Thank you for your advice but I still don't know how to make sure the file contains the source code :( I thought the file already contain source code when downloading vs code and install C/C++

Answer (score -1):

[Sample code with results displaying helloworld](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVHyT.jpg)

---

Not too sure if you're compiling the build and then executing? The link above will demonstrate using the terminal in VScode. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I also did the same as you but the terminal still reflected the same https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IdvLIhwAta3dUQS0qu1FnhCnA4XlQuaC/view?usp=share_link